# Mocking/Testing Vuex store modules is giving me TypeError problems

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuex

I'm still learning how to test components and js code but now I'm stuck with Vuex modules... Here is the code of the test:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import WorkoutsHistory from '../../src/components/WorkoutsHistory.vue'
import workout from '../../src/store/modules/workout'

const mocks = {
  $store: {
    modules: {
      workout
    }
  }
}
const propsData = {
  show: false
}

let wrapper

describe('WorkoutsHistory.vue', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(WorkoutsHistory, { mocks, propsData })
  })

  it('should match snapshots', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('should render the workout-list', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.workout-list')).toBeTruthy()
  })

})
```

And the imported module is:

```
import mutations from './mutations'

const state = {
  exercises: {},
  workouts: {}
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations
}
```

My problem here is simple, when I run the test, it returns me an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'workout/' of undefined`, which is weird for me due that I'm declaring the structure as is in the Vuex Store (I also tried with \createLocalVue). Here is the component script:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import NewExercise from './NewExercise'

export default {
  name: 'WorkoutsHistory',
  components: { NewExercise },
  data() {
    return { show: false }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('workout', ['workouts'])
  },
  methods: {
    showForm() { this.show = !this.show }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any idea or advice here?

Comment: You should definitely use createLocalVue as a minimum. Please have a look at this page https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because you are mocking the `$store` property on your component, but you aren't using that way in your component. Your component is using the `...mapState()` method, which will automatically expect that a `Vuex.Store()` was instantiated on a local copy of Vue. Take a look at the following link to properly mock up a Store for a local component's unit / integration test(s):

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html

Quick shoutout to @Anatoly, who provided the link.